# Isolated stimulator using optocoupler

Tags: opto-isolator

I would like to use an isolated circuit for my animal experiments. The stimulation protocol would be: pulses one after the other (I have already used a demultiplexer circuit for this) but now I want to apply simultaneous DC at 3 pairs, as well at 200uA. I built the circuit shown in the picture. At the bottom there is the TTL sequence.
[image]
I have a PIC16F1826 which gives a seperate TTL signal (25us On 50us Off pulses or 500 ms pulses) to two TLP521-4 optocouplers. My question is that this could work without collector/emitter resistors? Does the animal head act as an emitter resistor which would give an inverting output? Is there any other switching solution (for the switching one after the other the demultiplexer worked perfectly but it cannot handle the simultaneously active part of my experiments). The isolation and to use the same circuit is necessary for me.
I tested this circuit idea which is shown in the second figure.
And thats what I see with the oscilloscope. 
[image]
I know as I touch the isolated ground with the oscilloscope probe I lost the isolation. So my question is that this is only a measurement error or my whole circuit idea is not working? Why is there a DC shift at higher frequencies? What is that huge peak at the current controlled mode?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my basic misunderstanding but I am a medical doctor:)

Comment: Sounds like you are asking people on how to advise you to be cruel to animals. I'm sorry if I misunderstand your experiment but that's the way it goes with questions like this.

Comment: Cruel as a medical doctor? I wouldn't say but I can upload my ethcial permission if you need, and actually I am working on an alternative treatment of drug resistant epilepsy... to help patients, and the first step is always animal research. Here is one link how transcranial electrical stimulation can stop seizure: http://www.engineersjournal.ie/2013/09/19/epilepsy-defibrillator-prototype-stops-fits-from-starting/

Comment: An isolated probe will ensure that isolation is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

What you need, instead of a demultiplexer, is a micro controller with 8 output pins. You can then **program** the individual outputs to turn on one at a time or all at the same time, and any other combination in between.

There are cheap, simple, micro controllers readily available.  There are ARDUINO kits from $10 to $50 on eBay, with all kinds of online help for beginners (another micro is the Raspberry Pi).

I did not have time to answer your other questions.  So here they are.

You do not mention the voltage you are applying.  The safe thing to do is assume that the cranial resistance is zero.   since you need to limit the current to 200uA, if you use a voltage source of 2v, then you need a 10K limiting resistor (R = V/A).  So, using a 7.6k is a little on the low side, so definitely don't use the 1.8K.
As far as the NOT logic, it does not apply.  Each opto is just connecting **a side** of the supply.
Note:  Your connections diagram is wrong.  One side of the emitter resistor should go to the emitter, but the other should be connected to one probe and the emitter resistor of its pair, should be connected to the other probe.  Because of this, each emitter resistors should only be 1/2 of the total (7.6K), or 3.8K.